# How to select features based on multiple values in graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis, select, sextante

I'm trying to create a basic model using QGIS, the QGIS graphical modeler and the sextante toolbar. In part of the model, I need to select features based upon multiple attribute values (for example - A = 'value' OR A = 'another value'). The select by attribute algorithm provided by QGIS only allows you to enter a single value at a time - is there a simple tool/method to enter an expression to select multiple values from a dataset, and which can be incorporated in the graphical modeler?

Answer (score 1):

Just to move this question from the [*Unanswered*](https://gis.stackexchange.com/unanswered) section - the *Sextante plugin* has been renamed to the **Processing plugin**.

And as of version 2.9.0, you can use the **Select by expression** tool (separately or within the graphic modeler) which allows you to select features based on the expression provided.

[image: Select by expression]

This can include multiple attribute values, for example:

```
"column_A" = 'X' OR "column_B" = 'Y'
```

Comment: This is exactly the tool I need.  I have recently installed QGIS v. 2.18, but I do not see the "select by expression" option in my processing toolbox.  How can I find it?

Comment: @bwilkes - It should be made available. Exactly which QGIS 2.18 version are you using? Which algorithms are available to you? Also, make sure the "processing" folder is deleted in your `.qgis2/python/plugins/` directory.

Comment: Deleting the folder in my plugins directory totally did the trick!  Thank you so much!!  I'm also getting an unrelated error message upon startup.  I'm thinking my "upgrade" from 2.14 to 2.18 last week did not go smoothly... but that's probably a question for another thread.

Comment: @bwilkes - Most welcome, glad you solved it! You could always do a reinstall and see if the error message goes away :)

Comment: update went smoothly, error message gone!